# AWS CodeCommit getDifference for many directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Would like to build some integration with Amazon CodeCommit service. I would like to receive notification to my Lambda function with every push to `master` branch. I would like to use `getDifference` API method to check commit details but only in certain directories. I can call it multiple time for each directory I am interested in. But I would like to know if it is possible to fetch differences from all directories in one call using `afterPath` parameter. It works smoothly while fetching diff for one directory.

Answer (score 0):

There two task here.

Trigger to Lambda
Lambda should interact with git to find the difference of the changed files in a certain directory.

**CodeCommit Trigger:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-lambda.html

**npm git module:**

While there are lot of npm modules available, we use simple-git to achieve the work you want to do.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git

It can go through git repository and interact whatever you want to do with repo.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as GetDifferences goes, it looks like it will get differences in the root directory (and all subdirectories) if you don't specify afterPath. However, it limits the scope to the directory you provide in afterPath (and subdirectories therein). However, I don't think there's a way to provide multiple specific directories to afterPath in a single call, so making multiple calls is going to be your best bet.

Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetDifferences.html